# Vue JS - Rendering getter before template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

I'm getting TypeError "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" because it seems that the template is rendering before the getter returns the value. The value is indeed undefined as it is initialised as undefined in the store. But after the template renders, that value does return something. Is there anyway I can have my getter render after the template?

my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Success :title="'title name'"
             :subtitle="`your email is ${schoolDetails.email}.`"
             :button-text="'button text'"
             :button-link="ROUTE_NAMES_HK_ADMIN.SCHOOL_DETAILS"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ROUTE_NAMES_HK_ADMIN} from "@/router/modules/hkAdmin";
import Success from "@/components/partials/Success";
import {GET_SCHOOL_BY_ID} from "@/store/manager/actions";

export default {
  name: "SchoolCreateSuccess",
  components: {Success},
  data: () => ({
    ROUTE_NAMES_HK_ADMIN
  }),
  computed: {
    schoolDetails: function () {
      return this.$store.getters.getSelectedSchool;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getSchoolDetails: function (schoolId) {
      this.$store.dispatch(GET_SCHOOL_BY_ID, schoolId);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getSchoolDetails(this.$route.params.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about initializing the schoolDetails variable with dummy value to fulfil the error?
Then maybe you can use watch instead of computed to align tracking the schoolDetails variable with the stored data.

So, maybe something like this:

```
data: () => ({
  ROUTE_NAMES_HK_ADMIN,
  schoolDetails: {email: ''}
}),
// note: 'watch' track changes (no changes == the function will not be called)
watch: {
  // watch the state, not the getter
  '$store.state.selectedSchool': () => {
    this.schoolDetails = this.$store.getters.getSelectedSchool;
    return;
  }
}
```